# Java shows previous if clauses input again

Tags: java, if-statement

This is my Main class:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class Main {

    public static int menu = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        //boolean listeda= false

        System.out.println("Geben Sie ihre gewünschte Maximalmenge an Stylisten und Klienten an. (1.Stylist; 2.Client)");
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int z1 = in1.nextInt();
        int z2 = in1.nextInt();
        PersonData db = new PersonData(z1, z2);
        System.out.println("Ihre Datensätze können bis zu "+z1+" Stylisten und "+z2+" Klienten enthalten.");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Geben Sie ihre gewünschte Maximalmenge Terminen. (abhängig von ihren Speicherkapazitäten)");
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int z3 = in2.nextInt();
        AppointmentData adb = new AppointmentData(z3);
        System.out.println("Ihre Datensätze können bis zu "+z3+" Einträge enthalten.");
        System.out.println();

        int menu = Menu();
        while(menu != 99) {

            if(menu == 0) Menu();
            
            else if (menu == 1) {
                System.out.println("1");
                System.out.println();
            }

            else if (menu == 2) {
                //printMap(list); //Apointment get all Entries
                System.out.println("2");
                System.out.println();
                Menu();
            }
            else if (menu == 3){
                System.out.println("Geben Sie ihre gewünschte Maximalmenge Terminen. (abhängig von ihren Speicherkapazitäten)");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                //int a = in.nextInt();
                db.insertStylist("Chanti", "Mueller", "c.mueller@mail.de", 123123, "cut", "wash");
                System.out.println("Ihre Datensätze können bis zu "+in.nextInt()+" Einträge enthalten.");
                System.out.println();
            }
            else if (menu == 4){

            }
            else if (menu == 5){
                System.out.println("Geben Sie ihren gewünschten Termin an. (day, month, year, hour, min, service(s))");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                int a = in.nextInt();
                int b = in.nextInt();
                int c = in.nextInt();
                int d = in.nextInt();
                int e = in.nextInt();
            }
            else if (menu == 6){
            }
            
            Menu();

        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    
    public static int Menu(){ //Menü mit Auswahlmöglichkeiten
        
        System.out.println("menu="+menu);
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Terminplaner (Zahl eintragen)");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("[1] Neuen Termin anlegen");
        System.out.println("[2] Termine anzeigen lassen");
        System.out.println("[3] Stylist eintragen und anzeigen lassen");
        System.out.println("[4] Client eintragen und anzeigen lassen");
        System.out.println("[5] Termin eintragen und anzeigen lassen");
        System.out.println("[99] Programm beenden");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        switch(in.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Neuer Termin:");
                menu = 1;
                return menu;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Termine");
                menu = 2;
                return menu;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Datenliste für Stylisten und Klienten serialisieren.");
                menu = 3;
                return menu;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Datenliste für Termine serialisieren.");
                menu = 4;
                return menu;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Datenliste für Termine serialisieren.");
                menu = 5;
                return menu;
            case 99:
                System.out.println("Planer wird geschlossen");
                System.exit(0);
                menu = 99;
                return menu;
            default:
                System.err.println("Falsche Eingabe");
                Menu();
                return menu;
        }

    }
}
```

And if I enter 1 for example the program enters the right way, but if I put 3 afterwards the program does only the text for option 3 and then prints option 1 again. How do I fix this?

I know that  I need to enter the while loop again before the if statements but somehow my code seems to go back into the previous if clauses that were already triggered.

Comment: You assign `int menu = Menu();` the first time, and then every other time you call `Menu()` you never overwrite the value, you just ignore the return.

Comment: The local var `menu` shadows the member variable `menu`.

Comment: thank you so much Michael, I don't know how I missed this

Comment: @database_n00b np. i dont know what IDE you're using but IntelliJ showed me a warning "*menu is never updated in the loop*" on this line `while (menu != 99)` which made the problem obvious without me even needing to think much. It's free (the Community version anyway) and a lot of people think it's the best Java IDE. Would recommend it if you're not using it.

Comment: @Michael yeah that sounds good, right now I'm using Eclipse, but I'll probably switch